# Putting cube drawn using GLSurface into xml xode.(Fetching cube drawn from java code into xml code)

Tags: java, android

I wanted to put cube drawn using GLSurface into xml. I wanted to put that cube into my aaa(xml file).

I have search manything from stackoverflow, but i m not getting the output.

Means i wanted put two setcontentview into same oncreate method.

I wanted to put cube drawn using GLSurface into xml. I wanted to put that cube into my aaa(xml file).

I have search manything from stackoverflow, but i m not getting the output.

Means i wanted put two setcontentview into same oncreate method.

Plz help me. I m new to android.

Thank you.

My MainActivity code

```
package com.example.andriod.test;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.aaa);

GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) 
findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceViewID);


GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
view.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer());
setContentView(view);


 }




class OpenGLRenderer extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {


private Cube mCube = new Cube();
private float mCubeRotation;


@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(mCubeRotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    mCube.draw(gl);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    mCubeRotation -= 0.15f;
}

@Override

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 
   100.0f);
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

}

  @Override
  public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl,
                             javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig 
  config) {
    /*gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);*/
    gl.glClearColor(3, 9, 9, .5f);
    gl.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
            GL10.GL_NICEST);

 }




 class Cube {

    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mColorBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer mIndexBuffer;

    private float vertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };
    private float colors[] = {
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    private byte indices[] = {
            0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 1,
            1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2,
            2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 3,
            3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 0,
            4, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5,
            3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2
    };

    public Cube() {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mColorBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mColorBuffer.put(colors);
        mColorBuffer.position(0);

        mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
        mIndexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mColorBuffer);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                mIndexBuffer);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }
}

    public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);



    }

}

}
}
```

My xml code(aaa) I am trying to fetch for the id glSurfaceViewID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
android:ems="3"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:text="" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
android:text="Button" />
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
android:id="@+id/glSurfaceViewID"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_marginTop="800dp"
android:layout_weight="0.23" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I wanted to put cube drawn using GLSurface into xml. I wanted to put that cube into my aaa(xml file).

I have search manything from stackoverflow, but i m not getting the output.

Means i wanted put two setcontentview into same oncreate method.

Plz help me. I m new to android.

Thank you.

Comment: Plz help me...!

Comment: your help is much appreciated